# How to store obtain an md-select ng-model value within a dialog in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, angularjs-scope, angular-material

I have this template I am using to pass into an md-dialog box:

The showDialog function:

```
$scope.showDialog = function(element) {
var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
$mdDialog.show({
  template: element,
  scope: $scope,
  preserveScope: true,
  parent: parentEl,
  clickOutsideToClose: true,
  controller:function($scope) {
    $scope.answer = null;
   }
  });
}
```

Calling the showDialog function

```
$scope.showDialog(`<div class="md-dialog-container" id="functionality">
    <md-dialog aria-label="Dialog">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Who do you want to assign to build functionality?</label>
      <md-select ng-model="startAppController.fluff">
        <md-optgroup label="Select an Employee">
          <md-option ng-value={{employee.name}} ng-repeat="employee in staff" ng-selected="true">{{employee.name}}</md-option>
        </md-optgroup>
      </md-select>

    </md-input-container>
<div>
  <md-input-container flex-gt-xs>
    <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="startAppController.assign()">Assign Work!</md-button>
  </md-input-container>
  </div>
  </md-dialog>
</div>`);
```

I just got the *ng-click* portion working, so I can actually call that assign() function. However, I am not able to pass a variable into assign(), nor access the "fluff" variable from the md-select box.

I'm not certain how scope plays a part in this entire thing, but I seem to have it working mostly. I just can't access that fluff variable.

Comment: Any suggestion on my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

First, rather than passing `scope` from main controller to dialog controller and using `preserveScope`, You should pass data by using `locals` property.

Second, in you dialog's controller you should implement `$mdDialog.cancel()` and `$mdDialog.hide()` method to cancel or confirm the Dialog Box. Any argument that are passed in these methods will be accessible at in the controller which is calling this Dialog Box.

Third, return `$mdDialog.show()` and it will return a `promise`. Now, use `then` method to handle the promise as desired.

Here is the JavaScript

```
 $scope.showDialog = function(element) {    
  var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);

return $mdDialog.show({
    template: element,
    locals: { data: "Pass Any Variable"},
    parent: parentEl,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    controller: function($scope, data) {
      $scope.fluff = [];
      $scope.data = data;
      $scope.staff = {
        0: {name: "John Doe"},
        1: {name: "Lorem Ipsum"},
        2: {name: "Random Dude"},
        3: {name: "Kid"}
      };
      $scope.cancel = function(){
        $mdDialog.cancel();
      }
      $scope.submit = function(){
        $mdDialog.hide($scope.fluff);
      } 
    }
  });
}

$scope.openDialog = function(){
$scope.showDialog(`<div class="md-dialog-container" id="functionality">
<md-dialog aria-label="Dialog">
<md-input-container>
<label>Who do you want to assign to build functionality?</label>
  <md-select multiple ng-model="fluff">
      <md-option ng-value="employee.name" ng-repeat="employee in staff">{{employee.name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>

</md-input-container>
{{data}}
{{fluff}}
<div>
<md-input-container flex-gt-xs>
 <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="submit()">Assign Work!</md-button>
 <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Back</md-button>
 </md-input-container>
</div>
</md-dialog>
</div>`).then(function(response){
  $scope.data = response;
}, function(response){
  $scope.data = "cancelled";
});
}
```

Here is the working [Example](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/QpyBxY).